# Clicking social media icons (Font Awesome) not redirecting to href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code, but when I click the icons it doesn't redirect to the href links.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Blindthreatsnz/"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://blindthreatsnz.bandcamp.com/"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-soundcloud"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://youtu.be/2qETcJ00iXY"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://youtu.be/2qETcJ00iXY"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the URL - http://blindthreatshc.mycoffeeshopdemosite.com/

Comment: You have `$(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click',function(event) {  event.preventDefault();` in your code

Comment: You `disabled` click with some `javascript` or `jquery`

Comment: looks like a problem in your JavaScript, post that too. It's best if you make a fiddle demo that we can edit to show you how to fix.

Comment: looks like you're trying to do something with the other links in the nav bar to scroll to their positions on the page.. I would check for if hash is undefined then just open the link or do some other behavior

Comment: maybe do something like if(!!hash) then do the scroll block of code

Comment: If you just copy and paste that into plunker, it works. Like the other users have said, the problem is not in the html you posted.

Answer (score 3):

You have the following code in your HTML:

```
$(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event){ event.preventDefault()});
```

This prevents your clicks from continuing.
If you change it to the following, you can exclude your social links:

```
$(".navbar:not(.social) a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event){ event.preventDefault()});
```

Comment: ok so I did use this code $(".navbar:not(.social) a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event){ event.preventDefault()}); and the social media links are now working, but the smooth scrolling is now disable.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. The only thing you should change in your code is that selector from jQuery. The thing I added was the :not(.social). That's what you should add to your code and it should work fine. Sorry that I didn't paste your whole code!

Answer (score -3):

You are missing this tag target="_blank"

```
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Blindthreatsnz/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
```